# Odd syntax Error that I do not know how to fix

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I was creating a program in python 3 that asks your name, age, and a password. I am getting a syntax error and I do not know why.
Here is my code:

```
import time
needCheck = False
check = ("Just to check")
myName = ("Mason")
myAge = (12)
thePassword = ("Potatos are gud")
print("...")
time.sleep(3)
print("Scanning")
time.sleep(3)
print("*HUMAN_LIFEFORM DETECTED*")
time.sleep(2)
print("Greetings inhabitant of planet Earth")
name = input("What is your name, Earthling?")
if name == myName:
    print("Oh, it's you")
    needCheck = True
else:
    print("Salutations, " + name + "!")
if needCheck:
    age = input(check + ", " "what is your age?")
    if age == myAge:
        print("Looking good so far...")
    else:
        print("You're not fooling me anymore...")
        needCheck = False
else:
    age = input("What is your age " + name + "?")
    if age == myAge:
        print("Hmmm...")
if needCheck:
    pass = input(check + "again" + ", " + "what is the super secret password?")
    if pass == thePassword:
        print("I knew it was you!")
    else:
        print("You must be an imposter! Where is the real Mason?!")

else:
    pass = input("What is the super secret password, " + name + "?")
    if pass = thePassword:
        print("How did you know that?!")
        print("Self Destruct In:")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(3)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(2)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(1)
        while True:
            print(BOOM)
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

IDLE says the error is in this line, on the equals sign:

```
pass = input(check + "again" + ", " + "what is the super secret password")
```

If you know why it is invalid syntax, please answer.
Thanks!

Comment: don't use `pass`, it's a reserved word (`keyword`) try something like `should_pass` or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass is a reserved word. try using any other word and it should work

Comment: This is more of a comment and not an answer